# Attribute error for list of objects from collection?

Tags: flask, mongoengine, bson, flask-restful

We're using Flask-Restful for implementing an API. As database we use MongoDB and MongoEngine as ODM. To get MongoEngine to work with Restful, we followed [this blog article](http://blog.alienretro.com/using-mongodb-with-flask-restful/). For getting the correct json-format we using the builtin [marsheling-methods](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html). This works perfectly for single objects (e.g. one item of a collection), but when marsheling a list of objects (e.g. all items of a collection), an **AttributeError** is raised (although we use the same syntax as for single objects). This is how our model and our views look like (I don't paste the routes, as they are in a separate file and work).

model:

```
class Task(db.Document):
    name = db.StringField()
    description_mini = db.StringField()
```

views:

```
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('task_id', type=str)

task_format = {
    "name": fields.String,
    "description_mini": fields.String
}

class TasksView(Resource):

    @marshal_with(task_format)
    def get(self):
        tasks = Task.objects().all()
        return tasks, 200


class TaskDetailView(Resource):

    @marshal_with(task_format)
    def get(self):
        args = parser.parse_args()
        startup_id = args['task_id']

        task = Task.objects(id=task_id).first()

        return task, 200
```

full stacktrace:

```
AttributeError

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 257, in error_router
return self.handle_error(e)
File "/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 257, in error_router
return self.handle_error(e)
File "/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 397, in wrapper
resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
File "/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
File "/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 487, in dispatch_request
resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
File "/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 562, in wrapper
return marshal(data, self.fields), code, headers
File "/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 533, in marshal
return OrderedDict(items)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 52, in __init__
self.__update(*args, **kwds)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py", line 547, in update
for key, value in other:
File "/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 532, in <genexpr>
for k, v in fields.items())
File "/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/fields.py", line 104, in output
value = get_value(key if self.attribute is None else self.attribute, obj)
File "/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/fields.py", line 37, in get_value
return _get_value_for_keys(key.split('.'), obj, default)
File "/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/fields.py", line 42, in _get_value_for_keys
return _get_value_for_key(keys[0], obj, default)
File "/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/fields.py", line 51, in _get_value_for_key
return obj[key]
File "/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 152, in __getitem__
raise AttributeError
AttributeError
```

Comment: What is the full traceback? It's hard to help without know where the `AttributeError` occurred and which object doesn't have which attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you want to marshal a list you have to define the fields as a list as well.

I think this will work:

```
task_list_format = {
    'tasks': fields.List(fields.Nested(task_format))
}

class TasksView(Resource):

    @marshal_with(task_list_format)
    def get(self):
        tasks = Task.objects().all()
        return { 'tasks': tasks }, 200
```

I believe it is not possible to return a plain list using the marshaling support in Flask-RESTful, it always expects a dictionary. For that reason I put the list under a "tasks" key.

I hope this helps.

Comment: What if one were to write a test that sends a list of multiple tasks? Seems like this approach only will marshal the first object in a list. @Miguel - any idea?

Comment: Not sure I understand. This solution will marshal the entire list. Each item in the list will be processed as a nested entity.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the problem is that mongoengine's Queryset object lazily queries the database and that Flask-restful/restplus marshalling expects a list.

I could make it work with

```
task_format = {
    "name": fields.String,
    "description_mini": fields.String
}

class TasksView(Resource):

    @marshal_with(task_format)
    def get(self):
        tasks = Task.objects().all()
        return list(tasks)
```

Answer (score 0):

try `flask_restful.marshal_with_fields`:

```
>>> from flask_restful import marshal_with_field, fields
>>> @marshal_with_field(fields.List(fields.Integer))
... def get():
...     return ['1', 2, 3.0]
...
>>> get()
[1, 2, 3]
```